# Oracle PL/SQL Program Not Working, program involves Records and Composite Data

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a program for PL/SQL that isn't working just yet and I'm close at getting it to work but just need a little help seeing where I'm going wrong.

Currently, I have a program retrieves the earliest hired employee from an employee table, then enters that using %ROWTYPE into a RECORD and then displays that information to the user.

Everything is going well and as planned, just have a little problem with the variable declaration for the Longevity of the employee.  My earliest hire_date calculation from the sysdate isn't getting a result.  I am using the TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN) Calculation and putting that into the declared record.  So somewhere along the way the variable or the calculation isn't working.

Anyways, the main problem lies with the LONGEVITY calculation not working, it's just an age calculation.  This is the format and answer I'm supposed to get

```
Longevity: 9113.5 days or 303.8 months
```

Here is my coding, it's a little complicated following all the variables and records and declarations  I tried to make it basic and simple:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  TYPE hr_rec IS RECORD
    (
    hr_longevity        NUMBER(4, 1),
    hr_hire_date        employees.hire_date%TYPE,
    hr_rec_row          employees%ROWTYPE
    );
    hr_myrecord      hr_rec;

BEGIN

SELECT *  INTO hr_myrecord.hr_rec_row
 FROM
 (
     SELECT * 
     FROM  employees
     ORDER BY hire_date
 )
 WHERE rownum = 1;

hr_myrecord.hr_longevity := 
    TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, hr_myrecord.hr_hire_date), 1);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The employee info for Longest Employed is: '
|| hr_myrecord.hr_rec_row.employee_id
|| '  ' || hr_myrecord.hr_rec_row.first_name 
||  '  ' || hr_myrecord.hr_rec_row.last_name );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hire date is:  ' || hr_myrecord.hr_rec_row.hire_date);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Email address is:  ' || hr_myrecord.hr_rec_row.email);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Phone number is:  ' || hr_myrecord.hr_rec_row.phone_number);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Longevity is: ' || hr_myrecord.hr_longevity );
END;
/
```

HERE is what it gives me:

```
anonymous block completed
The employee info for Longest Employed is ID#:  100  Steven  King
Hire date is:  17-JUN-87
Email address is:  SKING
Phone number is:  515.123.4567
Longevity is:
```

Also, just for kicks, this is the example in my text that I'm supposed to go by to get this calculation, It's not very helpful but it is similar, just with a different calculation.

```
DECLARE
type t_rec is record
(v_sal number(8),
v_minsal number(8) default 1000,
v_hire_date employees.hire_date%type,
v_rec1 employees%rowtype);
v_myrec t_rec;
BEGIN
v_myrec.v_sal := v_myrec.v_minsal + 500;
v_myrec.v_hire_date := sysdate;
SELECT * INTO v_myrec.v_rec1
FROM employees WHERE employee_id = 100;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_myrec.v_rec1.last_name ||' '||
to_char(v_myrec.v_hire_date) ||' '|| to_char(v_myrec.v_sal));
END;
```

Comment: What is the datatype of employee.hire_date? Is that a date column? The calculation seems otherwise correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hr_myrecord.hr_hire_date` is not initialized before calculating `hr_myrecord.hr_longevity`
You may do the following:

```
hr_myrecord.hr_longevity := 
    TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, hr_myrecord.hr_rec_row.hire_date), 1);
```

Comment: I've come to learn through some of these examples that the the TRUNC works well for homework and such, but for not losing data you should always use TO_DATE.